# Scaling background with zoom

Tags: html, css

So, i'm trying to design my first page, and kinda trying to learn as i go.
I'm trying to design a one page website, that contains multiple backgrounds, so i divided each section of the website that will contain a different background into divs.
The background looks fine with a full sized window and 100% zoom on the page, but if i zoom in it gives me the option to scroll the page horizontally and it gets messed up, id like to make it so it just simply scales and it does not give me the scroll option.
I've tried setting the background size to cover the page, messed with the width of both the body and the div that contains the background but i can't seem to get it to work.
So, this is part of the page with 100% zoom:
[Fully scaled window 100% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZXA.png)

But when i reduce the window: it looks like this:
[Gives me scroll option and the background image cuts out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8y0e.png)

Heres the HTML code:
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvJet.png)

And heres the CSS:
[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m48ES.png)

Thanks, sorry for noob question.

Comment: could you https://htmlfiddle.net/ it and give us a link?

Comment: sounds like you wanna get into the Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com and go from there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xnjfLybh/

Comment: Yeah ive heard of it but i wanted to do it without it.

Comment: Use css breakpoints and you might be golden

Comment: I think it would be better to post a **minimal** example that reproduces the issue as a snippet, rather than using external sites like htmlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Alright i think i found a solution while just trying different stuff out:

i put on the html and body css:
overflow: auto;

It seems to have fixed my problem, i was kinda of just randomly trying stuff out.
Thx for the help.